# Python 3 Update MySQL database table

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I have just found the pymysql module for connecting Python to a MySQL database.  I have a database set up with a table named 'loot', loot contains a column called 'wins'.  My code contains a variable named 'won' that is given a value right before the SQL line.  I want the variable 'won' to be entered into the 'wins' column where id=1.  The id=1 row already exists in the database.

The code below throws an error `pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'won' in 'field list'")`

**My Question:** Why am I getting this error and what am I doing incorrectly?

**The Code:**

```
import pymysql

# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect(host='*******',user='******',password='*****',db='******')

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

won=1

# Prepare SQL query to UPDATE required records
sql = "UPDATE loot SET wins = won WHERE id = 1"

# Execute the SQL command
cursor.execute(sql)

# Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL isn't able to read the variable `won` so you must pass it in as an argument to `.execute()`:

```
won = 1
sql = "UPDATE loot SET win = %s WHERE id = %s"
cursor.execute(sql,(won,1))
db.commit()
```

Please note that you have to have a container of some sort as the second argument to `.execute()`. In this case it is a tuple.

Comment: im still learning :-)  This would actually be a tuple inside of a tuple?

Comment: This is a tuple inside of a method call.